# Keras dense layer outputs are 'nan'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm using Keras to build a RNN model with CTC loss.

I found that when passed a tensor to a Dense layer with `activation=None`, and the outputs of this layer were all `nan`.

But when set `activation='softmax'`, the outputs were `normal` not `nan`.

problem code (elements of logits are all `nan`):

```
logits = Dense(out_shape, activation = None, name="logits")(x_permute)#x_permute is a tensor with shape (?,1876,96)
loss_ctc = Lambda(ctc_lambda_func, name='ctc_my')(
    [logits, labels, x_len, lab_len])
model = Model(inputs=[x, labels, x_len, lab_len], outputs=[loss_ctc])
model.compile(loss={'ctc_my': lambda y_true,y_pred: y_pred}, optimizer='adadelta')
```

normal code(elements of logits are not `nan`):

```
logits = Dense(out_shape, activation = None, name="logits")(x_permute)#x_permute is a tensor with shape (?,1876,96)
output = Activation(activation="softmax", name="softmax")(logits)
loss_ctc = Lambda(ctc_lambda_func, name='ctc_my')(
    [output, labels, x_len, lab_len])
model = Model(inputs=[x, labels, x_len, lab_len], outputs=[loss_ctc])
model.compile(loss={'ctc_my': lambda y_true,y_pred: y_pred}, optimizer='adadelta')

def ctc_lambda_func(args):

    y_pred, y_true, input_length, label_length = args

    return ctc_batch_cost(y_true, y_pred,input_length,label_length)
```

Anyone helps? many thanks.

Comment: In your code you don't use the logits tensor at all. So the example makes no sense. Also why do you want to use your loss function inside the model?

Comment: Try another optimizer

Comment: My editorial mistake . I did use the  logits tensor , and  pass it to my CTC loss layer, but got 'nan' in the outputs of the  CTC loss layer.  I printed tensors in TF Debug and found the 'nan' began in the outputs of Dense layer. As for loss function, does Keras support CTC loss in its build-in loss function? I couldn't find it . Any idea of using CTC loss as loss function? waiting for your reply. thanks very much !

Comment: I tried 'SGD', 'Adam', 'Adagrad' as optimizer, but still got 'nan'.

Comment: In Keras you can write your own loss function https://keras.io/losses/. Normally you would use keras backend functions to be independent on the backend. But you can also use everything which can handle tensorflow tensors including builtin tensorflow functions. One more thing: I'm not sure if keras layers pass the name argument to the tensor. So executing both models in the same session with non unique names might be problematic.

Comment: emmm...finally I  use 'softmax' as activation funciton for compromise. thanks~

Answer (score 1):

I may misunderstand you, but why would you want activation="none"?
Maybe what you want to use is linear activation?

Have a look at  [Keras Activation Functions](https://keras.io/activations/)

Comment: Yes, I want to use 'linear' as activation function, so I left it actiavtion=None. Because I found that Keras call ctc_loss() which is Tensorflow's function to calculate the CTC loss . And ctc_loss() requires the inputs to be logits without activation.  I use linear activation but got nan . It makes me very confused  and takes me several days to locate the bug.

Comment: My bad, I was not aware that it defaulted to Linear.

Comment: Thanks anyway ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

as per [Klemen Grm](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/keras-users/LoTwUFO730M/ROqwyC0UCwAJ)

> your neural network is completely linear. You might consider different activation functions (eg: tanh, sigmoid, linear) for your hidden and output layers. This both lets you constrain the output range, and will probably improve the learning properties of your network.
>
> In addition to what Klemen says, for the last one you want a softmax,
> that normalizes the outputs into probabilities.

Neural networks have to implement complex mapping functions hence they need activation functions that are non-linear in order to bring in the much needed non-linearity property that enables them to approximate any function. A neuron without an activation function is equivalent to a neuron with a linear activation function

Comment: I see , I just test my CTC loss function , and have not added any other layers yet.